# Insert line after last row of specific text

Tags: excel, vba

I need find the LAST OCCURANCE of text and then:

1. insert a row below
2. copy the data only from columns b & c
3. keep the same formatting as the columns above

```
Cells.Find( What:="Multi Deck Case",
    After:=ActiveCell,
    LookIn:=xlValues,
    LookAt:=xlPart,
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows,
    SearchDirection:=xlPrevious,
    MatchCase:=False,
    SearchFormat:=False).Insert.EntireRow
```

This should help me with the first item - inserting a row below, but I think I'm doing something wrong in the last part (`Insert.EntireRow`)

Answer (score 3):

To find the last something in a column, use this code.
As for the rest, you will have to provide some code and ask a better question, that is not so broad in scope.

```
LastRowColb = Worksheets(1).Columns(1).Cells.Find("TEXT", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, LookIn:=xlValues, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

Replace TEXT with whatever you are looking for to get the row of the last occurrence.

Comment: I'm trying to find the last occurrence of text and insert a row

Comment: This will find the last occurrence of TEXT.  Then you can use the row number (LastRowColb) to do your insert.

Answer (score 0):

I did not articulate myself well in my question, but I figured out the correct code below:

```
Cells.Find(What:="Door Cases", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious,_
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).EntireRow.Select
ActiveCell.EntireRow.Insert
ActiveCell.Offset(RowOffset:=-1, ColumnOffset:=1).Activate
ActiveCell.Resize(1, 2).Copy
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
```